# Positioning Tooltip in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I use a Tooltip widget, inside this I use custom widget. Tooltip appears under the widget. How can I  place it on the right by widget?

```
class MenuItemWithTooltip extends StatelessWidget {
  const MenuItemWithTooltip({
    required this.item,
    required this.title,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final MenuItem item;
  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Tooltip(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(3)),
      ),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 55),
      textStyle: text12W400.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
      child: item,
      message: title,
    );
  }
}
```

[image: What would I like to see]

Comment: I don't think it is possible at least not without any tricks. Adjustments are either below or above and vertical offset, which I bet you already knew.

Answer (score 5):

modify `verticalOffset` and `margin` values can do such thing.

```dart
Tooltip(
      verticalOffset: -13,
      margin:EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
      message: "xxx",
      child:...)
```

[test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRHl4.png)

Comment: If you use this solution with a nav rail, as the OP suggests, you will not be able to click the button because the tooltip widget is invisibly overlaying the button due to the margin.

Answer (score 2):

As for positioning `Tooltip`, it does not go any further than setting `preferBelow` to `true` or `false` and adding offset or padding, which will make it appear either on bottom or top of the widget.

If you want more customization, you have to go with showing [OverlayEntry](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/OverlayEntry-class.html) on hover on your widget and then hide it on some condition or after duration. Much more trouble then simply using a `Tooltip`. But there alignments can be adjusted for your needs.

Some packages to look into, that simplify working with overlays:

https://pub.dev/packages/modals

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_portal